# better way for dynamic forms with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What I wonder is if there's a easier/better way to handle dynamic forms (adding form items to the dom via js) when using SpringMVC and Spring forms?

Imaging having an Invoice object that have many LineItems.

```
public class Invocie {
    private List LineItems;

    public Invoice() {
        lineItems = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList<LineItem>(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(LineItem.class));
    }
}
```

To show the items belonging to an Invoice I currently use

```xml
<forEach items="${invoice.lineItems}" varStatus="i">
  <form:input path="lineItems[${i.index}].productName" />
</c:forEach>
```

To add LineItems I have some js that calculates the new index and adds that to the DOM. When deleting a LineItem i currently have to renumber all the indexes and that's the part I'd like to avoid, is it possible?

Comment: Ok I hate to say it, but is there no way to make a Spring Controller accept what PHP accepts, I mean putting [] in the path ?

Answer (score 11):

I've implemented a tutorial that might help you solve this using jQuery on the client side and Springs AutoPopulating list for you form backing objects.

<del>http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/</del>

EDIT
Link from Webarchive https://web.archive.org/web/20160729163958/http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/

Comment: @eggsy84 What about removing objects dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following

```
public class InvoiceController extends SimpleFormController {

    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequetDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "lineItems", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class)() {
            protected Object convertElement(Object lineItem) {
                LineItem li = (LineItem) lineItem;

                // StringUtils is a jakarta Commons lang static class
                return (StringUtils.isBlank(li.getProductName())) ? null : li;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Then in onBind method, you remove null references according to:

```
protected void onBind(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, BindException bindException) throws Exception {
    Invoice invoice = (Invoice) command;

    invoice.getLineItems().removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
}
```

Regards,

Comment: They do walk together. This question wasn't really an issue, I am wondering if there's a better way than the lazyList from apache commons.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that also decorating with a GrowthList is necessary to avoid some errors when adding/setting items in JSP. (Also created a custom SpringList impl. that basically does the double decoration.)

```
lineItems = GrowthList.decorate(ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList<LineItem>(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(LineItem.class)));
```

I agree. The problem is certainly removing items.

What you can do is use the [spring marker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#setFieldMarkerPrefix(java.lang.String)) syntax in the html. So if you remove an item (at index 2 for example) from the list using javascript, you would then mark that index with:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_lineItems[2]">
```

Then when the form is submitted spring will see the marker and put in an empty item (based on the lazylist factory) for lineItems[2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html#setFieldMarkerPrefix(java.lang.String)) instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this problem today and figured out some solution described [here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2010-12-29-lazy-list-dynamic-forms/).