# Controller and View for creating one-to-many object, both "container" and unlimited number of "content" objects?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, one-to-many

Users will be able to write some documents. Those documents will consists of chapters (one-to-many relation).

Normally I would do this by creating separate views for creating chapter and document.

How to implement web page that allow to edit "composite" view? Where I can edit document details, but also create chapters, without visiting different pages? Also how can I ensure that I pass order of chapter user have arranged (by moving chapters freely up and down)?

(Sorry if that question already have be asked&answered but I do not even know how to search for it :| since I do not know proper keywords beyond "AJAX", so help in naming my requirement would also be welcomed!)

Comment: I'm not sure you can get an answer to that without someone actually replying with the all architecture for the application. AJAX is key of course for communication with the back end and avoiding page refresh but for the user interface there is many way to cook it and describe the all implementation would take some time.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671640/spring-3-mvc-managing-a-one-to-many-relation-within-a-dynamic-form-using-a) is the way I solved a quite similar problem. Hope that could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Partial solution.
Just google Nested Forms Ruby on Rails. Plenty of examples, all in ajax, all easy.

Answer (score 0):

Backend servers applications based on REST principles work nicely with Ajax client-side implementations.

For example, your URLs could be:

```
/book/1
/book/1/chapters
/book/1/chapter/1
```

You could set it up so that a POST to /book/1/chapters would add a chapter.  A GET on that same URL would return all chapters.  A GET on /book/1/chapter/1/ would only return chapter 1. A PUT on /book/1/chapter/1/ would update an existing chapter. This is a "RESTful" architecture:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

This is an interesting introduction: http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife

This is a big subject, but if you create the right backend server architecture you will find your job a lot easier.  Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Ok, that is server side :) Now some tips about client side, pls.

Comment: Well, your book editor application would probably consist of a few pages-  one for managing books, one for editing books, maybe a settings page...  Then, you could write your application in HTML and JavaScript, using Ajax to communicate with your RESTful server.  Several JavaScript libraries will help ease the integration with the server, like jQuery or YUI.  You could take it a step further and use something like Backbone.js, which would encapsulate your domain objects into JavaScript objects, and hides the server communication.  Only a few chars left, so Hope That Helps!