# Is ArrayList a valid @ModelAttribute? How can I create a form that populates it?

Tags: java, html, spring

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'll keep my code and idea generic since I've seen a few examples of people with similar problems:

The basic idea is that the view has a list of order items with properties that the user can modify inside a form. When the user submits the form, I want the order items populated with the data that the user submitted.

How do I create the HTML form that populates this `@ModelAttribute("orderItems")` which is an `ArrayList` of `OrderItemBean`s

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping("/order/{orderId}/save")
public String saveOrder(Map<String, Object> map, @ModelAttribute("orderItems") ArrayList<OrderItemBean> orderItems) throws Exception
{
  ...    
}
```

Java Bean Code: (getters and setters implied)

```
public class OrderItemBean
{
  String orderItemId;
  String itemName;
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as I am still learning about Spring.

Comment: Try the solution described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890250/better-way-for-dynamic-forms-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

I always use declaration params via interface.

try change ArrayList -> List

also be sure that your OrderItemBean declarate with @XmlRootElement annotation and under context.